# Умные подсказки при наведении

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery, css3

Как можно сделать такие подсказки при наведении на пункты навигации?

Но чтобы учитывалась ширина экрана, а именно, чтобы подсказка не выходила за пределы экрана, когда наводишь на крайние пункты навигации.

[image: Подсказки]

Comment: https://popper.js.org

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Использовать псевдоклассы [last-child](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/:last-child) и [first-child](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/:first-child)

```css
* {margin: 0; padding: 0;}
ul {
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 75px 15px 0 15px;
}
li {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #000;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
}

li span {
  position: absolute;
  left: 15px;
  top: -50px;
  width: auto;
  padding: 15px 30px;
  color: black;
  background: #ffbb00;
  border-top-left-radius: 5px;
  border-top-right-radius: 5px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
  display: none;
}

/* ↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓ */
li:last-child span {
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
  left: unset;
  right: 15px;
}

li:hover > span {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><p>1</p><span>Hint</span></li>
  <li><p>1</p><span>Hint</span></li>
  <li><p>1</p><span>Hint</span></li>
  <li><p>1</p><span>Hint</span></li>
  <li><p>1</p><span>Hint</span></li>
  <li><p>1</p><span>Hint</span></li>
  <li><p>1</p><span>Hint</span></li>
  <li><p>1</p><span>Hint</span></li>
  <li><p>1</p><span>Hint</span></li>
</ul>
```